# Enable HTTP2 on Apache WebServer OS X

Tags: macos, apache, nginx

I added this line on httpd.conf file

`LoadModule http2_module libexec/mod_http2.so`

But I am getting this error

`httpd: Syntax error on line 144 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/mod_http2.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/mod_http2.so, 10): image not found`

How do I enable HTTP2 on Apache WebServer on OS X?

Comment: If you are talking about Apache distribution which comes with the operating system, it doesn't include HTTP/2 support. Consider looking into whether Apache available through Homebrew (https://brew.sh/) does.

Comment: Did you figure out how to install it on Mac? I am looking to do the same